# Averaging and Grouping In google Big Query

Tags: google-bigquery

I have the table as shown in google big Query:

[image: Table]

I just want to do the following:

1. Calculate Category wise total units sold
2. Calculate  Category wise average selling price

Answer (score 2, accepted):

consider below approach

```
select 'category' type, category name, count(1) units_sold, sum(sale_price) total_sale, round(avg(sale_price), 2) average_selling_price 
from your_table group by category
union all
select * from (
  select 'product' type, product name, count(1) units_sold, sum(sale_price) total_sale, round(avg(sale_price), 2) average_selling_price 
  from your_table group by product
  order by total_sale desc limit 10
)
union all
select * from (
  select 'order_date' type, '' || order_date name, count(1) units_sold, sum(sale_price) total_sale, round(avg(sale_price), 2) average_selling_price 
  from your_table group by order_date
  order by total_sale desc limit 5
)
order by type
```

if applied to sample/dummy data - output would be like below

[image]